# Exclude a row from a table which is not useful in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Thes table always shows me rows which are not useful. for a NaN value I used this expression here to exclude it:

```
   iif(Fields!GoodUnits.Value=0 or Fields!TheoreticalUnits.Value=0,
           0, (Fields!Unit.Value / Fields!Sum.Value)
```

now it shows me 0 Values. I would like to exclude thes row which is not useful in my table.

Comment: Is this a query issue? It sounds like your query is sending a row with these values to begin with, so you could try excluding it there.

Comment: yes this is a query issue, how can I exclude it in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an issue with the query, here's my suggestion *without knowing the data*. Wrap your entire query inside an inline view, and make a where clause to eliminate the 0.0 rows. Such as:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TheoreticalUnits, IPaddress from YOUR-TABLES) main
where main.TheoreticalUnits <> 0.0
```